# Make optional property in the formgroup

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a formgroup with optional property. imageName should be optional.

### Component

```
this.formbuilder.group({
      details:[''],
      date:[''],
      imageName : ['']
    })
```

Comment: Does it give any error if you dont provide imageName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this with formBuilder

```
this.formbuilder.group({
  details:['', Validators.required],
  date:['', Validators.required],
  imageName : ['']
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with generating a formGroup like this

```js
formGroup: FormGroup;

this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      details: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      date: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      imageName: new FormControl(null)
    });
```

And in your HTML, you can set each input with `formControlName`

```html
<input type="text" formControlName="details">
```